# Trouble centering header

Tags: html, css

I just want to center these 4 anchor tag `li`s inside of this `ul`.

Is there someway I can wrap these four into one container, and then move them to the left with `CSS`? I just want those 4 items to appear centered in that ul.

Here's a picture of what I'm talking about

Below is my total header in `HTML`. There's a lot of `CSS` so I don't know what to link people to but I'll put what i have been playing with below.

```
    <!-- Header -->
        <header class="header header-fixed header-fixed-on-mobile header-transparent" data-bkg-threshold="100">
            <div class="header-inner">
                <div class="row nav-bar">
                    <div class="column width-12 nav-bar-inner">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <div>


                                <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"  style="color:grey; display:inline-block">1-530-680- 
                                        8255</a>

                                         <a href="tel:1-530-680-8255"><i class="fas fa-phone" style="display:inline-block"> 
                                          </i>1-530-680-8255</a>



                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <nav class="navigation nav-block secondary-navigation nav-right">
                            <ul>



                                    <li class="aux-navigation hide">
                                        <!-- Aux Navigation -->
                                        <a href="#" class="navigation-show side-nav-show nav-icon">
                                            <span class="icon-menu"></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        <nav class="navigation nav-block primary-navigation nav-center">
                            <ul>

                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home <i class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">About <i class="fas fa-at"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Services <i class="fas fa-wrench"></i> </a></li>
                                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Contact <i class="fas fa-phone"></i> </a></li>


                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Header End -->
---CSS---

nav ul li  {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
width: 100px;
margin: 00px;
padding: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Robbie. Did you forget to upload the picture of what you want? and can you add more of the CSS you have that is related to that nav menu please? and are you using a framework? :)

Comment: Wrap it in a container with width:100% and margin: 0 auto. Or utilise flexbox. Probably.

Comment: That's ok. I don't need to see the CSS. I commented on Zeth's answer below. If you go with his original answer (before he made an edit) and then position your logo with position: absolute it should sit inline with the nav menu and the container will be vertically the right height again. And thank you for the compliment haha :)

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by adding this css (instead of the one you've displayed):

```
<style>

  .logo {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 30%;
    float; left;
    display: block;
  }

  .navigation {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    max-width: 70%;
    float: right;
    width: 700px;
  }

  .navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .navigation ul li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

So you can just add all that code in the `<head>`-section of your site, and then it should work.

Comment: Hey thanks this centered it. However the container is vertically too large now. If i can get it down to the previous size that would be a complete solution. any thoughts? I'll post an answer here with two screenshots so you can see what i mean just lookout for my post.

Comment: I just updated my answer. Try that? ... I remove `width: 100%` on `.navigation` and on `ul`.

Comment: also, im confused. YOu say to add it to the head section...in my html file?

I stuck this in my CSS file. What do yo mean by adding to the head file? All my previous html code i put here? That is in the body fwiw.

Comment: Hey Zeth, your new code fixed the height, but now its off center again! Man this is such a puzzle..

Comment: The container is probably vertically too large because your logo is also within it (and im guessing your logo is position relative). If you add the following CSS to your logo: position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 0px; then the height of the container will go back to normal

Comment: My advice is use @Zeths original answer and position the logo with position absolute;  top: 30px; left: 0px;

Comment: And yes putting the code in your CSS file instead of the <head> section is fine :)

Comment: I just updated my answer again, trying to add some styles to the other element in the div (`.logo`). But in order to be able to supply you a full working example, then I would need to know a bit about the sizes of the different elements, which can grow - and how it should work on smaller devices. But it's probably something you would have to play around with a bit yourself, I'm afraid. ... But try this updated answer out. How does that work?

Comment: Thanks Sarah, that worked. NOW the phone number is cut off. So how do I keep the phone number inline and fully displayed the way it was? Ill post a screenshot below.

Comment: zeth thank you, i tried your updated code and it still throws it way off to the left now. I think the problem here is that there is CSS for the logo to invert colors as i scroll down, so there is so much to consider, and something is getting lost in translation here. i dont have the savvy to explain it, im a newb. I wish i had worked with a bootstrap friendly theme, which i will do next time, because the grid system with that is so easy to use. Anyways, Sarahs answer pretty much solved it, except now the phone number on the left is cutoff halfway and displaying the rest further down.

Comment: Ok thats good it worked. I'll keep an eye for the screenshot. (Fyi its a good idea to add the images to your question as an edit, instead of posting them as answers-just a heads up) :)

Answer (score 0):

Sarah, or others:

The solutions provided have centered it, however the phone number is now cutoff.

[cutoff phone number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUx0R.png)

Im including all of what i think is the relevant CSS. I hope this isnt too much to sift through, i just have no clue what is causing this.

```
    [4. Header Styling]
*/

/* Initial Position */
.header-bottom{
    bottom: 0.1rem;
}

/* Intial Height */
.header .logo,
.header .header-inner .navigation > ul > li,
.header .header-inner .navigation > ul > li > a:not(.button),
.header .header-inner .dropdown > .nav-icon{
    height: 8rem;
    line-height: 8rem;
}

/* Compacted Height */
.header-compact .logo,
.header-compact .header-inner .navigation > ul > li,
.header-compact .header-inner .navigation > ul > li > a:not(.button),
.header-compact .header-inner .dropdown > .nav-icon{
    height: 6rem;
    line-height: 6rem;
}

/* Header Initial Styling */
.header .header-inner{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.header .header-inner > .nav-bar{
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;*/
}

/* Transparent Header Initial & Active Nav Colors */
.header-transparent .header-inner{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
.header-transparent .header-inner > .nav-bar{
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);
}

/* Background Header - On Scroll! */
.header-background .header-inner{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #eee;
}
.header-background .header-inner > .nav-bar{
    border-bottom: none;
}

/* Header Inner Top */
.header .header-inner-top{
    height: 4rem;
    background: #232323;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Mobile Header Styles & Breakpoints */
.mobile .header .header-inner{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: none;
}
.mobile .header .header-inner{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.mobile .header + .content{
    padding-top: 0;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px){
    .header .header,
    .header .header-inner,
    .header.header-transparent .header-inner{
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .header .header-inner{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    .header .header-inner > .nav-bar{
        padding: 0;
    }
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[5. Header Logo]
*/

/* Initial Logo Width */
.header .logo{
    width: 12.5rem;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

/* Compacted Header Logo Width */
.header-compact .logo{
    width: 12.5rem;

}

/* Initial Logo Styling */
.header .logo a{
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.header-in .logo a,
.header-out .logo a{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0ms;
    transition-duration: 0ms;
}
.header .logo a:first-child{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.header .logo a + a{
    display: none !important;
}

/* Transparent Header Show Light Logo */
.header-transparent .logo a:first-child{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(5rem);
    transform: translateY(5rem)
}
.header-transparent .logo a + a{
    display: block !important;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

/* Header Background Logo Swap to Dark Logo - On Scroll! */
.header-background .logo a:first-child{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.header-background .logo a + a{
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5rem);
    transform: translateY(-5rem);
}

/* Logo Nav Dark */
.nav-dark .logo a:first-child{
    display: block !important;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.nav-dark .logo a:last-child{
    display: none !important;
}

/* Logo Mobile Header & Breakpoints */
.mobile .header .logo a:first-child{
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px){
    .header .logo-inner{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .header .logo a{
        position: relative;
    }
    .header .logo a:first-child{
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
        transform: translateX(0) !important;
    }
    .header .logo a:last-child{
        display: none !important;
    }
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[6. Header Navigation]
*/


/* Padding & Margins */

<style>
  .navigation {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
  }

  .navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navigation ul li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
  }
</style>


.header .logo-center ~ .navigation.nav-center{
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
}
.header .logo-center ~ .navigation.nav-center > ul > li > a{
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.header .navigation > ul > li > a{
    margin: 0 1.5rem;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

/* Header Initial & Active Nav Colors */
.header .navigation > ul > li > a{
    color: #999;
    opacity: 1;
}
.header .navigation > ul > li.current > a,
.header .navigation > ul > li > a:hover{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 1;
}
.header .navigation > ul > li.current > a:hover{
    color: #000;
}

/* Transparent Header Initial, Hover & Current Nav Colors */
.header-transparent .navigation > ul > li > a{
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.header-transparent .navigation > ul > li > a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
}
.header-transparent .navigation > ul > li.current > a,
.header-transparent .navigation > ul > li.current > a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Nav Dark Initial, Hover & Current Colors */
.header-transparent.nav-dark .navigation > ul > li > a{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.nav-dark .navigation > ul > li.current > a,
.nav-dark .navigation > ul > li.current > a:hover{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Header Background Initial, Hover & Current Nav Colors - On Scroll! */
.header-background .navigation > ul > li > a{
    color: #999;
}
.header-background .navigation > ul > li.current > a{
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.header-background .navigation > ul > li.current > a:hover{
    color: #000;
}
.header-background .navigation > ul > li > a:hover{
    color: #000;
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Sub Menus, Mega Menus, Dropdown List Initial Colors */
.navigation .sub-menu li,
.navigation .dropdown-list li{
    border-bottom: none;
}
.navigation .sub-menu li a,
.navigation .mega-sub-menu ul li a,
.navigation .dropdown-list li a{
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #888;
}
.navigation .sub-menu:not(.custom-content) li a,
.navigation .dropdown-list:not(.custom-content) li a{
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}
.navigation .mega-sub-menu > li > a{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.navigation .sub-menu:not(.custom-content) a,
.navigation .sub-menu.custom-content,
.navigation .mega-sub-menu,
.navigation .dropdown-list{
    background-color: #111;
}

/* Menu Nav Cart Intial Colors */
.navigation .cart .badge{
    top: -0.4rem;
    left: 1.2rem;
    background-color: #9a9484;
}
.navigation .cart-overview .product-title{
    color: #fff;
}
.navigation .cart-overview .product-price,
.navigation .cart-overview .product-quantity{
    color: #999;
}
.navigation .cart-overview a.product-remove{
    background-color: #444;
    color: #999;
}
.navigation .cart-overview .cart-subtotal{
    color: #fff;
}
.navigation .cart-overview .cart-actions{
    border-color: #444;
}
.navigation .cart-overview .checkout.button{
    background-color: #9a9484;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}
.navigation .cart-overview .checkout.button:hover{
    background-color: #666;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Sub Menus, Mega Menus, Dropdown List Hover Colors */
.navigation .sub-menu:not(.custom-content) li:hover > a,
.navigation .mega-sub-menu:not(.custom-content) ul li:hover > a,
.navigation .dropdown-list:not(.custom-content) li:hover a{
    background-color: #000;
}
.navigation .sub-menu li > a:not(.button):hover,
.navigation .mega-sub-menu ul li > a:not(.button):hover,
.navigation .dropdown-list li > a:not(.button):hover,
.navigation .cart-overview .product-title:hover,
.navigation .cart-overview .product-remove:hover{
    color: #fff;
}
.navigation .sub-menu li.current > a:not(.button),
.navigation .dropdown-list li.current > a:not(.button),
.navigation .mega-sub-menu ul li.current > a:not(.button){
    color: #fff;
}

/* Mega Menu Position */
.navigation .mega-sub-menu{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/* Labels Sub Menu */
.sub-menu li .label,
.mega-menu li .label,
.dropdown li .label{
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.1rem 0.4rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #9a9484;
    border-color: #9a9484;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I think you should edit your .logo CSS as follows: try top: 15px; instead of top: 30px; You can play around with this value to get the phone number to sit at the same height level as the menu items text.  and also in your .logo class it looks like there's a width of 12.5rem. Try making it wider e.g width: 400px; so that the full phone number fits within it.

Comment: Also just as an extra thing. In your HTML it looks like there's spacing in the phone number (just before 8255). remove this to see if it solves it. :)

Comment: awesome i appreciate your help so much! this is working!  

I wish i understood it inside out, so i could know for next time. But i think ill make sure im using bootstrap since i understand that fairly well haha

Comment: That's great! No probs glad to have helped. Yea frameworks are much easier haha :)

Comment: Sarah how do i add you as a friend or is that not a thing on SO

Comment: It's not a thing on SO. :/

Comment: lol. I'm not on facebook at the mo but you can catch me on twitter. @monksee :)

Comment: hey Sarah mind helping me with putting an email address next to that number? cant seem to get it right